# I won't go with you or come with you

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct go or come ?

For example:

A: B come with me!.

B: No I won't go with you / come with you.

Answer (score 1):

> Go with X to Y

Emphasis is on X leaving somewhere.

> Come with X to Y

Emphasis is on X moving to a new destination and being part of X.

Also:

> Why don't you go with us to the movies? (Implies you are independent of the group going to movies for some reason.  For example, you may be taking your own car.)
>
> Why don't you come with us to the movies? (Maybe you are riding with them.)

Answer (score 0):

You always use in response the word that the other person used, so if you responded to someone who had said, "Come with us", you would say, "No, I won't come with you."

Answer (score 0):

'go with you' and 'come with you', both are not always interchangeable.
 so, you should say 'No, I won't come with you'.